# RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type EmittingStream has been deleted

Tags: python, pyqt5, runtime-error

I am trying to create a basic GUI where a user clicks one of 4 buttons and the respective scripts are called in the background, and stdout is redirected to a textEdit widget.
The program works by correctly calling the functions on button clicks and then redirecting stdout to the textEdit widget, however whenever the program is closed, I get the error.

"RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type EmittingStream has been deleted"

I think my problem has to do with bad ownership semantics where the dialog constructor owns the emmitingstream class and then terminates itself, but honestly I have no idea.
Sorry if this is a repeat question, but I don't think this relates to other questions with deleted wrapped C/C++ objects. This is my first project with pyqt, and I cannot figure out how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
import ARINC_TFTP_DATALOADER_SERVER as DL
import sys

#Stream for write signal
class EmittingStream(QtCore.QObject):

    textWritten = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def write(self, text):
        self.textWritten.emit(str(text))

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def run(self):
        if (dialog.code == 1):
            DL.FIND_DL()
        elif (dialog.code == 2):
            DL.INFORMATION_DL()
        elif (dialog.code == 3):
            DL.DOWNLOAD_DL()
        elif (dialog.code == 4):
            DL.UPLOAD_DL()
        else:
            exit(1)
        self.finished.emit()

class Dialog(QDialog, object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()

        self.createMenu()
        self.createHorizontalGroupBox()
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.handleFinished)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        #Cancel Buttons
        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        #Text window
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textEdit.setDisabled(True)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("ARINC 615a Maintenance")

        # TextStream THIS IS WHERE I AM STRUGGLING
        sys.stdout = EmittingStream(textWritten=self.normalOutputWritten)
#What actually writes
    def normalOutputWritten(self, text):
        cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(text)
        self.textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.textEdit.ensureCursorVisible()

    def createMenu(self):
        self.menuBar = QMenuBar()

        self.fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        self.exitAction = self.fileMenu.addAction("E&xit")
        self.menuBar.addMenu(self.fileMenu)

        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.accept)

    def handleButton(self, button):
        self.btn_grp.button(1).setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_grp.button(2).setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_grp.button(3).setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_grp.button(4).setEnabled(False)
        self.code = self.btn_grp.id(button)

        self.thread.start()

    def handleFinished(self):
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()
        self.btn_grp.button(1).setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_grp.button(2).setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_grp.button(3).setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_grp.button(4).setEnabled(True)
    def createHorizontalGroupBox(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox("Operations")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.button1 = QPushButton("FIND",self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)

        self.button2 = QPushButton("INFORMATION",self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.button3 = QPushButton("DOWNLAOD",self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button3)

        self.button4 = QPushButton("UPLOAD",self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button4)

        self.btn_grp = QButtonGroup()
        self.btn_grp.setExclusive(True)

        self.btn_grp.addButton(self.button1)
        self.btn_grp.setId(self.button1, 1)

        self.btn_grp.addButton(self.button2)
        self.btn_grp.setId(self.button2, 2)

        self.btn_grp.addButton(self.button3)
        self.btn_grp.setId(self.button3, 3)

        self.btn_grp.addButton(self.button4)
        self.btn_grp.setId(self.button4, 4)

        #self.textEdit.clear()
        self.btn_grp.buttonClicked.connect(self.handleButton)

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':


    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

I am not set on this way of redirecting stdout, if anyone else has a suggestion please lmk.

Comment: You should restore stdout before quitting (`def closeEvent(self, event): sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`) and connect the cancel button to `self.close` instead of `self.reject` (you don't need accept at all).

Comment: @ekhumoro Wow, thank you I couldn't figure this out for the longest time, I didn't think the error had to do with stdout. creating a close event fixed it, thank you so much!!!